# No VNET option for Azure PostgreSQL Server

Tags: azure, vnet, azure-postgresql

I am trying to add my PostgreSQL server to an existing VNET, however, I can't find the option to do so. I was able to add my app service and even found this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/howto-manage-vnet-using-portal) for PostgreSQL, but the UI under "Connection Security" does not give me the option!

[image]

Does anybody have a work around?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you could use [Virtual Network service endpoints and rules for Azure Database for PostgreSQL - Single Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/concepts-data-access-and-security-vnet). Please note that This feature is available in all regions of **Azure public cloud** where Azure Database for PostgreSQL is deployed for **General Purpose and Memory Optimized server**s. .

I don't face this missing option. Please check if your DB for PostgreSQL server price tier is General Purpose.  You could try to clear your web browser cache then create your DB with different methods. You can create an Azure Database for PostgreSQL server [in the Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/quickstart-create-server-database-portal) or [using Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/quickstart-create-server-database-azure-cli) or [using PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/quickstart-create-postgresql-server-database-using-azure-powershell) or using [ARM template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/quickstart-create-postgresql-server-database-using-arm-template?tabs=azure-portal) .

For more information, see [Create and manage VNet service endpoints for Azure Database for PostgreSQL - Single Server using Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/howto-manage-vnet-using-cli)